# Text to Speech in South Vietnamese accent

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to use a South Vietnamese accent with android Text to Speech. I set `Locale("vi")`, but this speaks in a north Vietnamese accent.

"103" becomes "một trăm linh ba", but I want this to be "một trăm lẻ ba".

```
val textToSpeech = object {
    val value: TextToSpeech get() = inner
    private val inner = TextToSpeech(
        context
    ) {
        value.language = Locale("vi")
        value.speak("103", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null)
    }
}.value
```

Comment: Since you've already tried "vi".... have you tried "vi_VN"?

Comment: What language is that? Kotlin?  It looks unfamiliar.  What TTS engine is being used by the TTS object? ... and what Vietnamese voices are available to it?